# How to make socket.io talk with SSL

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, socket.io, long-polling

I want to make socket.io the JavaScript version talk with SSL. When I try engine.io gives a polling error about mixed content.

Server code below.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('./secure.key', 'utf8'),
    certificate = fs.readFileSync('./secure.crt', 'utf8'),
    credentials = { agent: false, requestCert: true, rejectUnauthorised: false, key: privateKey, cert: certificate },
    app = require('https').createServer(credentials, handler),
    url = require("url"),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    path = require("path");
var zlib = require('zlib');
var config = require('./config');

    io.sockets.on('connection', socketHandler);

    function socketHandler(socket)
{
    GLOBAL.sockets[GLOBAL.sockets.length] = socket;
    socket.playerId = nextPlayerId++;
    socket.pingDate = new Date();
    socket.broadcast.emit('player_connect', {playerId: socket.playerId});
    socket.emit('player_id', {playerId: socket.playerId});

    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.socketFunctions.length; i++)
        eval("socket.on(GLOBAL.socketFunctions[" + i + "].name,function (data)   { GLOBAL.socketFunctions[" + i + "].action(socket,data); });");
}

app.listen(config.httpsport, "ipaddress", function() {
  console.log('listening on port', config.httpsport);
});
```

When I run the code now will SSL cert I get an error.

```
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. polling-xhr.js:264
```

No socket.io/engine.io requests appear to be getting through and setting `DEBUG=socket.io* node server.js` appears to show nothing useful (nothing related to failure of transport due to SSL.

I noticed these sort of issues come up a lot with SSL but must have tried a dozen different proposed solutions on various forums and the socket.io glitter and none of them seem to work.

This is a very important project for me at the moment and I really would be tremendously grateful for any help anyone can offer.

At this stage I would be happy even to switch off the SSL for socket.io stuff, as long as it remained in place for the other parts of the site (we need to add a new payment system), but I'd prefer a complete solution if possible.

Comment: What does the client-side socket.io code look like?  Are you serving the web page over https?

Comment: We took it out because we couldn't figure out how to fix it. Using something else now.

Comment: then you should probably delete your question if you arent going to engage to solve it.

Comment: @jfriend00 we're porting the entire codebase to a different framework, the upshot is that it will be better and more efficient, but the development process will take longer. This isn't a case of 'not engaging'

Comment: Are you going to work with us here to solve this problem or not?  If not (because you've changed your implementation and this is no longer relevant - which is perfectly fine), then please delete this question.  It does nobody any good to have a question just sitting here with no answer and nobody working on it.  Let's disposition this one way or the other.